# clear content of the column if the header is blank vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to clear all the columns that have a blank header at the work sheet.

```
Set names = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 100))

For Each Cell In names
    If IsEmpty(Cell.Value) Then
    Cell.Columns.ClearContents
    End If
 Next Cell
```

And I see nothing changing but the code running. Is there a logical error here? maybe here:

```
    Cell.Columns.ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
For Each cell In Names
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        Dim col As Range
        Set col = cell.EntireColumn
        col.ClearContents
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: just what I was thinking; you can even bring that down to one line by doing `cell.EntireColumn.ClearContents`

Comment: Good call, I thought that would result in an object required error, but I tested and you are indeed correct.

Comment: yep. that is cool. Kinda funny how Cell.Columns.ClearContents doesn't work but EntireColumn does :)

Comment: `cell.columns` refers to all the columns within the cell range-which is just that cell ;-)